# Defining a macro in Scheme to create fancy sublist

Tags: functional-programming, macros, scheme, racket

I would like to resolve a problem about macro:

> Define this construct:
>   `(subl e_1 e_2 ... -> e_i ... e_j <- e_j+1 ... e_n)`;
>   its evalutation returns the sublist `(e_i ... e_j)`.
>   E.g. `(subl 1 -> 2 3 4 <- 5 6)` should be `(2 3 4)`.

I tried to solve it (the following is a partial solution) but it didn't work...

```
(define-syntax subl
  (syntax-rules(> <)
    ((_  x y ... > x ... y < c v )
     (begin
       '(x y)))))
```

The error is :

> syntax-rules: misplaced ellipsis in pattern (follows other ellipsis)
>   in: ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use multiple ellipsis in a single pair of brackets, it doesn't matter if you are using the keywords `->` and `<-` the language is not clever enough to know where to stop the expansion.

Examples:
`(_ x ...)` is legit and `x ...` captures everything until the closing bracket.
`(_ x y ... z)` is legit and `x` matches a single element at the beginning, `y ...` captures everything, but the last element and `z` matches a single element at the end.
`(_ (x ...) y ...)` is legit and `x ...` captures everything inside the inner brackets and `y ...` everithing inside the outer brackets.
`(_ x ... y ...)` it is **not** legit, since you can't tell how far to expand the two groups.

So you have to address the problem in multiple steps: remove the elements before `->`, remove the elements after `<-` and finally capture the list in the middle.

```
(define-syntax subl
  (syntax-rules (-> <-)
    ((_ -> x ... <-)
     '(x ...))
    ((_ -> x ... y)
     (subl -> x ...))
    ((_ x y ...)
     (subl y ...))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make patterns that transforms your source to something simpler to process:

```scm
(define-syntax subl
  (syntax-rules (-> <-)
    ((_ "build-list" end middle before)
     (subl "execute" before middle end))
    ((_ "build-list" before () () -> . rest)
     (subl "build-list" () () before . rest ))
    ((_ "build-list" middle () before <- . rest)
     (subl "build-list" () middle before . rest ))
    ((_ "build-list" (xs ...) the others x . rest)
     (subl "build-list" (xs ... x) the others . rest))
    ((_ "execute" before middle end)
     ; I guess this is wrong
     'middle)
    ((_ . rest)
     (subl "build-list" () () () . rest))))

(subl a b c -> d e f <- f g) ; == '(d e f) => (d e f)
```

What is does is to change the format you would like the code to have to something simpler.  `(subl a b c -> d e f <- f g) => (subl "execute" (a b c) (d e f) (f g))` then you have the logic you want in the pattern for "execute".

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your macro using Racket's [`syntax-parse`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Parsing_Syntax.html?q=syntax-parse#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._syntax-parse%29%29) (since you included the [racket](/questions/tagged/racket) tag :) ), which has a more expressive pattern language than `syntax-rules`.

```
#lang racket
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-syntax (subl stx)
  (syntax-parse stx #:datum-literals (-> <-)
    [(_ a b ... -> c ... d <- e ... f)
     #:when (printf "a: ~a\n" (syntax->datum #'a))
     #:when (printf "bs: ~a\n" (syntax->datum #'(b ...)))
     #:when (printf "cs: ~a\n" (syntax->datum #'(c ...)))
     #:when (printf "d: ~a\n" (syntax->datum #'d))
     #:when (printf "es: ~a\n" (syntax->datum #'(e ...)))
     #:when (printf "f: ~a\n" (syntax->datum #'f))
     #''(c ... d)]))

(subl 1 -> 2 3 4 <- 5 6)
```

produces:

```
a: 1
bs: ()
cs: (2 3)
d: 4
es: (5)
f: 6
'(2 3 4)
```